# Apply not:last-child to article

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have the following markup

```
<div>
  <article>article 1</article>
  <article>article 2</article>
  <article>article 3</article>
  <article>article 4</article>
  <ul class="pagination">
    <li>Page 1</li>
    <li>Page 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I tried to apply a bottom border to each article but not to the last one:

```
article:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: 8px solid #404040;
}
```

But with this I get a botton border on last article.

If I remove the UL then the last article does not get a border.

This is strange because I am only applying the style to article.

How can I solve this?

Thank You,
Miguel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be [`last-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3alast-of-type) instead of `last-child`.

```
article:not(:last-of-type) {
  border-bottom: 8px solid #404040;
}
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/hiral/P8KhR/)

Answer (score 2):

`:last-child` matches any child, not just `article` elements. `ul` is the last child, so every `article` matches your selector. You want to use `:last-of-type` instead:

```
article:not(:last-of-type) {
    border-bottom: 8px solid #404040;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`last-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3alast-of-type) instead `last-child`

```
article:not(:last-of-type) {
  border-bottom: 8px solid #404040;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xC246/)

Answer (score -1):

With the first `$(div)` we select our `div`, in `.find('.article')` we find all the articles inside that `div`. Then with `.last()` we choose the last article from the selected articles. And with `.css` we add the style to that article.

```
$('div').find('.article').last().css('border-bottom','none');
```

Comment: The first $(div) we have select our div, in .find('.article') we have find all the articles inside that div. Then with .last() we choose the last article from the selected articles. And with .css we add the style to that article :)